# Typescript / Javascript custom Property decorators

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I've just started to learn in more depth Typescript and ES6 capabilities and I have some misunderstandings regarding how you should create and how it actually works a custom Property Decorator.

This are the sources that I'm following
[Source1](https://gist.github.com/remojansen/16c661a7afd68e22ac6e)
[Source2](http://www.sparkbit.pl/typescript-decorators/)

And this is my custom deocrator.

```
export const Required = (target: Object, key: string) => {

    let value: any = target[key];

    const getter = () => {
        if (value !== undefined) return value;

        throw new RequiredPropertyError(MetadataModule.GetClassName(target), key, ErrorOptions.RequiredProperty)
    }

    const setter = (val) => value = val;

    if (delete this[key]) {
        Object.defineProperty(target, key, {
            get: getter,
            set: setter,
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true,
        });
    }
}
```

It is applied like so

```
export classMyClass{
    @Required
    public Items: number[];
}
```

What I don't understand is why it works differently then what would you expect. Well it works but I don't know if it works accordingly to the let's call it "decorator philosophy",

Let me explain what I don't understand

Starting with the first line of code.

```
 let value: any = target[key];
```

I would expect that the `value` would be initialized with `Items` value, but instead is `undefined`, why? how? i really don't understand.

I've followed both sources and that first thing that I find it confusing is the fact that one used `target[key]` to initialize the `value` while the other used `this[key]`, shouldn't `this` refer to the Required actually.

What I also find confusing is this part

```
 if (delete this[key]) {
        Object.defineProperty(target, key, {
            get: getter,
            set: setter,
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true,
        });
    }
```

Firstly, why I need to delete this[key] ? from my understanding this should refer to the current object context in my this case `Required`, and when debugged it is as so.

Secondly, that Object.defineProperty will create a property with the name of the key on the target class in my case `MyClass`, but isn't this property already there?

Moving forward and setting the `value` using the setter, how does the setter parameter `val` know what data it should hold ? I mean where is it coming ?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of questions in there, but I'll try to answer them all :)

> I would expect that the `value` would be initialized with `Items` value, but instead is `undefined`, why?

When your `MyClass` class is instantiated and your decorator code is run, the value of all properties of the object are `undefined` (even if you use a TypeScript property initializer, which you aren't).

> Shouldn't `this` refer to the `Required`?

Yes, I think it does in your example.  But in your [Source1 link](https://gist.github.com/remojansen/16c661a7afd68e22ac6e), the decorator is defined using a function expression (`function logProperty()`); in your example, you have switched this to an arrow function expression (`const Required = ( ... ) =>`).  It's likely this switch will change what `this` refers to.  To be safe, switch this to `target[key]`.

> Why I need to delete this[key]?

This block of code is deleting the original `Items` property and replacing it with a property of the same name that allows you to spy on the getting and setting of the variable.  The `delete this[key]` line is guarding against the case where the property isn't configurable.  ([The `delete` operator returns `false` if the property in question is non-configurable:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)).

> Object.defineProperty will create a property with the name of the key on the target class in my case `MyClass`, but isn't this property already there?

Yes, as mentioned above - this code is replacing the property with a new property.  The new property is set up to allow you observe the getting and setting of this variable.

> Moving forward and setting the `value` using the setter, how does the setter parameter `val` know what data it should hold ? I mean where is it coming ?

When your new `Items` property is set, the `setter` function is called with the soon-to-be new value of the property as a parameter (this `setter` function was previously set up as a setter function using `Object.defineProperty`).  The implementation of this `setter` function sets `value`, which is a reference to `target[key]`.  As a result, the value of `Items` gets updated.

---

To better understand how all this is working, try adding in some logging statements and then play around with getting/setting the `Items` property:

```
export const Required = (target: Object, key: string) => {
    let value: any = target[key];

    console.log('Initialize the Required decorator; value:', value);

    const getter = () => {
        console.log('Inside the getter; value is:', value);
        if (value !== undefined) return value;

        throw new RequiredPropertyError(MetadataModule.GetClassName(target), key, ErrorOptions.RequiredProperty);
    };

    const setter = val => {
        console.log('Inside the setter; val is: ', val, 'value is:', value);
        return (value = val);
    };

    if (delete this[key]) {
        console.log('Replacing the "' + key + '" property with a new, configured version');
        Object.defineProperty(target, key, {
            get: getter,
            set: setter,
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true
        });
    }
};

export class MyClass {
    @Required 
    public Items: number[];
}

// instantiated your class
var mc = new MyClass();

// set the Items property
mc.Items = [4, 5, 6];

// get the value with no Errors
mc.Items;

// set the Items property to undefined
mc.Items = undefined;

// get the value - an Error is thrown
mc.Items;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really helped me understand how things work, really appreciate it :)